# Reason for defining Riemannian curvature tensor and torsion tensor in particular way

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I saw how Riemannian curvature tensor and torsion tensor are defined, but I am not sure why they are defined that way. In 3-dimensional euclidean space with ordinary multivariable calculus, the concept is very straightforward, but I couldn't grasp how these tensors are actually defined as they are.

Comment: Hmm. Anyone....?

Comment: I'm afraid that the reason you are not getting any response is that you are asking for a blind shot: it is quite unclear what you are actually asking about. Could you please give more background, or rephrase it in a way that one could see how to help you?